# String.prototype.includes not converted to ES5

Tags: babeljs

ES6's `String.prototype.includes` function is left as is when compiling to ES5 (CLI babel 5.0.9)

Sorry if this a FAQ, I did search thoroughly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Babel converts ES6 syntax into ES5 syntax. It is up to you to load a polyfill so that new ES6 library functions are available. Generally you'd do this with

```
import 'babel/polyfill';
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. It would be better if you didn't have to add that line to your code, and just be able to do your normal `babel es6.js > es5.js` and by default everything that's in the ES6 specification gets converted to ES5.

Comment: Babel is a syntax transformer, it doesn't automatically add the polyfill because what polyfill you load is entirely dependent on the user. If you are only using modern browsers, `/polyfill` is probably overkill since it is the broadest polyfill.

Comment: That makes practical sense. But there is also a case to be made for a tool that converts ES6 (all of it, as per the ECMA-262 6) to ES5, which you could use independent of your browser (assuming it covers all of ES5 of course), and doesn't ask you to specify what parts of the specification you use, but just converts whatever new ES6 syntax or function you use.

Comment: Babel converts the syntax, and the polyfill implements all the new libraries in ES5, so you'd like the polyfill to be added automatically? What do you gain by automatically adding the polyfill vs adding it as part of the build process that you already need when using Babel? Where do you add it? Babel just compiles individual files, does every file then need to verify that the polyfill is loaded before executing?

Comment: Ideally I shouldn't even have to know what a polyfill is. I would run `babel *.js` and babel would add the function implementations needed to the output ES5, only once at the start of the first file, for instance.

Comment: But `String.prototype.includes` is a global, so injecting it at the top of every file would either constantly overwrite the existing global, or be extra code with no effect. Feel free to join the Babel Slack channel if you want to chat, I don't think SO comments are a great way to discuss this.

Comment: I kinda agree about having the polyfill included automatically.
When running a tool to convert ES6 syntax to ES5, I also expect to polyfill ES6 methods as well.
If not you end up with a source partially converted and not usable on old browsers.
Arguably, this is the job the of building tool (webpack, grunt, gulp, ...) to add the polyfill through config.

Comment: This answer is NO LONGER relevant. True for 15.12.19. `String includes` and `Array includes` and many other methods are not part of Babel `preset-env`. This means they are not transpiled and cause Errors in IE10/11 for example.


Further, `@babel/polyfill` has been deprecated and it's documentation is totally broken...
If anyone knows a clear and elegant way to import polyfills that Babel for some reason does not have like string `includes` I would love to understand what approach you took.